# OpenIdDict: Google and Facebook logins not displaying the account selection window

Tags: c#, asp.net, google-signin, facebook-login, openiddict

I am using OpenIdDict to authenticate users. I have implemented Google and Facebook logins following the example given [here](https://kevinchalet.com/2022/12/16/getting-started-with-the-openiddict-web-providers/), but the account selection window does not open if the user has already logged in to Google or Facebook at least once.

According to Google's documentation, I need to add the prompt=consent parameter to the URL to force the user to re-accept the application. However, I don't know how to do this with OpenIdDict.

Code:

Program:

```
var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);
//Some settings

builder.Services.AddOpenIddict()
.AddClient(options =>
{
    options.AllowAuthorizationCodeFlow();
    options.AddEncryptionCertificate(certificate)
           .AddSigningCertificate(certificate);
    options.UseAspNetCore()
           .EnableRedirectionEndpointPassthrough();
    options.UseWebProviders()
            .AddGoogle(options =>
            {
                options.SetClientId(builder.Configuration["Google:ClientId"]!)
                       .SetClientSecret(builder.Configuration["Google:ClientSecret"]!)
                       .SetRedirectUri(builder.Configuration["Google:RedirectEndpoint"]!);
            });
});
```

Controller:

```
[HttpGet("auth")]    
public IActionResult ExternalAuth(string provider)
{
    string? redirectEndpoint = provider switch
    {
        Providers.Google => _googleRedirectEndpoint,
        Providers.Apple => _appleRedirectEndpoint,
        Providers.Facebook => _facebookRedirectEndpoint,
        _ => null
    };
    if (redirectEndpoint == null)
    {
        return BadRequest($"Provider \"{provider}\" is not configured.");
    }
    var properties = new AuthenticationProperties(new Dictionary<string, string?>
    {            
        [OpenIddictClientAspNetCoreConstants.Properties.ProviderName] = provider,
    });
    return Challenge(properties, OpenIddictClientAspNetCoreDefaults.AuthenticationScheme);        
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `AuthenticationProperties.Parameters`:

```cs
var properties = new AuthenticationProperties(new Dictionary<string, string>
{
    [OpenIddictClientAspNetCoreConstants.Properties.ProviderName] = Providers.Google
})
{
    RedirectUri = Url.IsLocalUrl(returnUrl) ? returnUrl : "/",

    Parameters =
    {
        [Parameters.Prompt] = Prompts.Consent
    }
};

return Challenge(properties, OpenIddictClientAspNetCoreDefaults.AuthenticationScheme);
```